# Binding Kendo grid data after selecting from a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a screen where I have a `Kendo grid`.
I have a `dropdown` with years, and if I select a year the grid should refresh with corresponding data.

[image]

But after I select a date the returned result is the JSon result

[image]

What am I missing here?

This is the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GGISServices.Models.District.LotAutorizationSentDocumentsViewModel>()
    .Name("districtGrid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "newGrid" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        ....     
    })
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
    .ColumnMenu(f => f.Enabled(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .Info(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
        )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(c => c.Id).Descending()) // <-- initial sort expression
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "SentDocument", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.District }))
        .PageSize(25)
    )
    )
```

This is the `GetData` method from `controller` :

```
public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int year = 0)
    {
        var list = dsService.GetSentDocumentsAsQueryable(year);
        DataSourceResult result = list.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => x.ToViewModel());
        return new LargeJsonResult() { Data = result , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

and this is the `onChange`  event of the year dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#Year").on("change", function (e) {
           $("#gridDiv").load("@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")District/SentDocument/GetData/?year=" + $(this).val(), function () {
              });
        });
    });
```

When I choose another date, the `GetData` method is invoked with the selected year, but I don't know how to bind to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Mark_Fitzpatrick approach will work but the problem is with the way your controller is sending back the information from experiencing similar issues. The grid is expecting to see a DataSourceResult request back and you are changing the expected schema. so changing your controller from:

```
public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int year = 0)
    {
        var list = dsService.GetSentDocumentsAsQueryable(year);
        DataSourceResult result = list.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => x.ToViewModel());
        return new LargeJsonResult() { Data = result , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }


    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int year = 0)
        {
            var list = dsService.GetSentDocumentsAsQueryable(year);


            return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

This should return the data in the format the grid is expecting. If the data is large and assuming the `LargeJsonResult` is a custom return object you can simply just return the `JsonResult` with a max length setting assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach. Use the .Data() method to denote a javascript function that will return additional fields to send back to the server. Add this onto your read action on the controller and you can conditionally determine if this should be obeyed.

```
<script>
function myFunc(){
return {selectedDate: $("#myDatePicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value()};
}</script>
```

Then the read call looks like:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "SentDocument", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.District }).Data("myFunc"))
```

Then add the DateTime? selectedDate parameter onto your controller.

Your grid has the ability to gather all the information it needs to grab it's data. You don't have to worry about swapping the data source around. When your datepicker is changed (or any other field you may want to add for grid criteria), simply call the grid's dataSource.read() method to get fresh.

Comment: I've tried your approach, but I get the same result. - after I change the date the debugger enters on the controller method, but it returns the data in json format, as it is in the second screenshot from my question. I'm using this way:  .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "SentDocument", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.District }).Data("myFunc"))       function myFunc() {
        $("#Year").trigger("change"); 
                    return { year: $('#Year').find(":selected").text() };
    }